# Python write binary data to MIME infoset

Tags: python, binary, httplib2

I am tring to post an HTTP request using httplib2 that contains some xml and some binary data using this infoset:

```
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: Multipart/Related;boundary=MIME_boundary;
...
--MIME_boundary
Content-Type: application/xop+xml; 

// [the xml string goes here...]

--MIME_boundary
Content-Type: image/png
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
Content-ID: <http://example.org/me.png>

// [the binary octets for png goes here...]
```

My approach is to generate a txt file, and then fill in the xml and the binary data.

I am having problem writing binary data to the file reading from the png with this:

```
pngfile = open(pngfile, "rb")
bindata = pngfile.read()
```

What's the best way to do this?

Comment: What is exactly the problem with your approach?

Answer (score 0):

My advice is to use Python's standard mime library as in [these examples](http://docs.python.org/library/email-examples.html).
Try with this:

```
from email.mime.image import MIMEImage
from email.mime.base import MIMEBase
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart

msg = MIMEMultipart()
# Attach XML
xml = MIMEBase('application','xop+xml')
xml.set_payload(<xml data here>)
msg.attach(xml)

# Attach image
img = MIMEImage(<image data here>, _subtype='png')
msg.attach(img)

# Export the infoset
print msg.as_string()
```